# How can i write the equivalent of this sql server stored procedure to mysql?

Tags: mysql

my sql server's stored procedure code is:

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[MasterReport_SP]
(@masterReportRecNo bigint)
AS
DECLARE @updateDateCriteria varchar (500)
DECLARE @spCriteria varchar (3000)
DECLARE @sqlCommand1 varchar(3000)
DECLARE @sqlCommand2 varchar(3000)
DECLARE @sqlCommand3 varchar(3000)
DECLARE @transNo varchar (50)



BEGIN TRY


if @underwriterState = ''
begin
set @underwriterState = null
end

Set @totalEndtPremium = 0

Set @sqlCommand1 = ''

if @updateDateCriteria is NOT NULL
begin
if @underwriterState is NOT NULL
    begin
    Set @sqlCommand1 = 'DECLARE transDetails Cursor for Select policyNumber, policyTerm from trans'
    end
else
    begin
    Set @sqlCommand1 = 'DECLARE transDetails Cursor for Select policyNumber, policyTerm, policyIssueDate from trans'
    end
end

IF @sqlCommand1 is NOT NULL
BEGIN
    EXEC (@sqlCommand1)
    OPEN transDetails
    FETCH NEXT FROM transDetails INTO @policyNumber, @policyTerm, @policyIssueDate, @transactionNo
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
        BEGIN
            Print @policyNumber
            Set @systemCalcPremium = 0
            Set @premium = 0

        end;
```

i am facing problem due to this line:
**Set @sqlCommand1 = 'DECLARE transDetails Cursor for Select policyNumber, policyTerm from trans'**.because mysql does'nt allow this.**is there any alternative of this line in mysql.**

Comment: Do you really need the dynamic cursor? In MySQL, dynamic courses are not as simple as implemented in MSSQL Server.

Comment: yes it is necessary. i want to use again fetch next from.....in IF @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 block , and if i do this it shows undefined cursor. because scope of this cursor is limited in if else.

Comment: Article [MariaDB/MySQL: Cursors for Dynamic SQL](https://falseisnotnull.wordpress.com/2013/01/08/mariadbmysql-cursors-for-dynamic-sql/), it is an option, and can help you achieve what you want to accomplish.

Comment: thnx i implemented this using the view